# Linux - How do I capture and modify the input of a specific device (eg. a keyboard)

Tags: linux, keyboard, libraries

I have 2 keyboards, 1 for typing, and one for gaming. I would like to write a program to capture the output of one specific keyboard and remap the keys for that keyboard only. What libraries exist that allow me to do this (python libraries would be optimal for me!)?

Answer (score 0):

You could program a Keyboard hook for that keyboard.
I did the same thing before and it worked perfectly with [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13998277/1063093).

This solution is applied to a single keyboard but you get the point you need to tweak it a little but use the same native constants.

Good luck with that.

Comment: Great, thanks! Is it common practice on this site to post a full solution (or a link to said solution) after the fact?

Comment: @Cronanius After you fixed your issue ? No it is not. When you find the solution to your problem, you can point it out byt accepting the answer you judge helped you the most by clicking on the little checkmark under the answer's score.

Comment: @Cronanius, yes, if it's a full solution you can post another answer. Make sure to credit the origin and don't simply copy-paste copyrighted material. If it's a link only, you can just add a comment to your Question. If PhaDaPhunk's answer helped you to get there, make sure to mention it. See [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)